# How to modify a formula to include another element input inside my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my [pricing page](https://www.carryr.webflow.io/pricing), I've got a pricing estimator; input an order value and a return rate (%) and price estimate will print into a div block below. The formula should look like this: ((orderValue * 0.05, 2) + 4) + ((returnRate / 100) * 4)... Can anyone see why this isn't working?

```
var elDeliveryPrice = document.getElementById('deliveryPrice');
var elOrderValue = document.getElementById('orderValue');
var elReturnRate = document.getElementById('returnRate');
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('gb-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });

elOrderValue.addEventListener('keyup', _ => {
    let curVal = elOrderValue.value; 

    let curValFloat = parseFloat(curVal);
    if (isNaN(curValFloat)) {
        elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = '';
        return;
    }

    elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = formatter.format(Math.max(curValFloat * 0.05,2) + 4) + (parseInt("elReturnRate") / 100)) * 4;
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I am counting bad number of paranthesis in this line : 

formatter.format[P1](Math.max[P2](curValFloat * 0.05,2)[EP2] + 4)[EP1] + [P3](parseInt[P4]("elReturnRate")[EP4] / 100)[EP3])[EP?] * 4

I'd suggest to divide that long line to different variables before passing it to html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that cause your issues. For starters you should also listen to 'keyup' on the returnRate input box. Secondly you should handle NaN of the returnRate value.

For example:

```
var elDeliveryPrice = document.getElementById('deliveryPrice');
var elOrderValue = document.getElementById('orderValue');
var elReturnRate = document.getElementById('returnRate');
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('gb-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });

function calc() {
   let curVal = elOrderValue.value; 

    let curValFloat = parseFloat(curVal);
    let curRate = parseFloat(elReturnRate.value);
    if (isNaN(curValFloat) || isNaN(curRate)) {
        elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = '£ _';
        return;
    }

    elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = formatter.format(Math.max(curValFloat * 0.05,2) + 4 + (curRate / 100) * 4);
}

elOrderValue.addEventListener('keyup', calc);
elReturnRate.addEventListener('keyup', calc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide a percent number by 100 to get the correct number to include in your calculation. If the return rate input is given in text, you can convert to a number using parseInt(returnRate) e.g.

```
Math.max(curValFloat * 0.05,2) + 4 + (parseInt(returnRate) / 100) * 4
```

Comment: For some reason this hasn't worked - check out my [test page](https://carryr.webflow.io/pricing)